# Envio de email con url de mi aplicación

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

Tengo la siguiente problematica. El problema es que necesito enviar un email que contenga la URL que direcciona a la vista necesaria para que un cliente pueda acceder a la aplicación ya que en la app no pueden ingresar otros tipos de usuarios, se necesita que al momento de ingresar por medio de la URL se le dé acceso para que pueda entrar a la vista por un tiempo determinado, al concluir ese tiempo y quiere entrar por medio de la URL denegarle el acceso.
Solamente espero una idea de como solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Es una gran pregunta, ¿no? Tienes que generar algún tipo de token que se adjunte a la URL y que se valide cuando lo abran para dar acceso temporal y que esa validación del token revise la fecha-hora de creación para ver si ya pasó mucho tiempo. Como la pregunta no tiene ni una línea de código, ¿qué respuesta esperas? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.